# Como seria este codigo de vb en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Necesito mostrar datos que están en una base de datos. Tengo algo similar hecho en vb.net pero ahora me toca hacerlo en c#

```
 For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim codigo As Integer = dt.Rows(i).Item("CodDepartamento")

            html.Append("<tr>")
            html.Append("<td>")
            html.Append(dt.Rows(i).Item("CodDepartamento"))
            html.Append("</td><td>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que la variable `dt` es un DataTable y `html` un StringBuilder.

Sería algo así:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var codigo = (int) dt.Rows[i]["CodDepartamento"];

        html.Append("<tr>");
        html.Append("<td>");
        html.Append(dt.Rows[i]["CodDepartamento"]);
        html.Append("</td><td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de una manera bastante sencilla:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows){
    int codigo = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CodDepartamento"]);

    html.Append("<tr><td>").Append(codigo).Append("</td><td>");
}
```

Esto asumiendo que `dt` es un `DataTable` y que `html` es un `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Más que una solucion a tu pregunta es un consejo, existen varias herramientas que tienen la finalidad de hacer la conversión de codigo de VB a C# y viceversa.

Personalmente utilizo esta: http://converter.telerik.com/ pero hay varias..

Es posible que necesites convetir código nuevamente entonces ahí vas a tener una herramienta que lo haga por ti teniendo en cuenta que entiendes la lógica para programar.
Volviendo a tu pregunta el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
    int codigo = dt.Rows(i).Item("CodDepartamento");

    html.Append("<tr>");
    html.Append("<td>");
    html.Append(dt.Rows(i).Item("CodDepartamento"));
    html.Append("</td><td>");
}
```